# How to remove old p-trap clean-out plug

Tags: p-trap

I have a slow draining bathroom sink that backs up into my bathtub and vice versa.  I have removed what I thought was the clean-out plug, but there is move metal beneath.  Maybe I only removed the cover.  How can I remove the metal underneath the clean-out plug so that I can clear the debris in the drain?

Comment: Pictures would greatly improve the odds of getting a useful answer.

Comment: If the sink is backing up in the tub the problem is usually further down the drain line , as for a plug in the bottom of a trap it may just be debris built up there that look solid , possibly a rubber seal, have you tried poking it ? I don’t ever remember a inner plug on these kind of traps.

Comment: For anyone who may encounter the same problem:  beneath the clean-out plug, there was what looked like rusty metal.  I thought it might be a disc beneath the cover.   I tried pouring boiling water, followed by baking soda and vinegar, followed again by boiling water.  The second time I did this, water began to pour out of the clean-out plug whole.  I ran more water, and a stronger stream came through.  I then pushed on what I thought was a metal disc blocking the water, to find that it was sediment, and broke as I pushed on it.  A few more flushes should have it fixed!